# How to get the pointer to the middle of an array in c#

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, arrays, memory-pool

First, basic info on our environment: We're using c# .net 4.0, on Win7-x64, targeting 32-bit.

We have a preallocated -large- array. In a function, we would like to return a pointer to an arbitrary point in this array, so that the calling function can know where to write. Ex:

```
class SomeClass {
    void function_that_uses_the_array() {
       Byte [] whereToWrite = getEmptyPtrLocation(1200);
       Array.Copy(sourceArray, whereToWrite, ...);
    }
}

class DataProvider {
    int MAX_SIZE = 1024*1024*64;
    Byte [] dataArray = new Byte[MAX_SIZE];
    int emptyPtr=0;
    Byte[] getEmptyPtrLocation(int requestedBytes) {
       int ref = emptyPtr;
       emptyPtr += requestedBytes;
       return dataArray[ref];
    }
}
```

Essentially, we want to preallocate a big chunk of memory, and reserve arbitrary length portions of this memory block and let some other class/function to use that portion of memory.

In the above example, getEmptyPtrLocation function is incorrect; it is declared as returning Byte[], but attempting to return a single byte value.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, you can't do this in C# - and generally you *shouldn't* do anything like it. Work with the system - take advantage of the garbage collector etc.

Having said that, if you want to do something similar *and* you can trust your clients not to overrun their allocated slot, you could make your method return [`ArraySegment<byte>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx) instead of `byte[]`. That would represent "part of an array". Obviously most of the methods in .NET don't use `ArraySegment<T>` - but you *could* potentially write extension methods using it as the target for some of the more common operations that you want to use.

Comment: I heard the garbage collector argument a few times, but our testing so far shows that pre-allocating does help. Could it be very dependent on the characteristics of the application? In our application, we need to allocate/deallocate between 2K-128K of memory (different sizes every time), at around 250 times per second.

Comment: @SomethingBetter: Have you considered preallocating *complete* arrays of various sizes, and allowing the caller to just get a buffer of a different size, rather than a subarray within one big array?

Comment: Maybe, but the lengths vary greatly and it causes a lot of fragmentation/empty space. Actually, one of my fundamental problem is that I can't read data into an arbitrary position into an array, since we're using a 3rd party library. I've posted that as another question here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895799/pinvoke-pointers-and-array-copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895799/pinvoke-pointers-and-array-copy). I'd appreciate any insight. --thanks

Comment: @SomethingBetter: It's relatively unusual for an API like that not to take an index into the array (like Stream.Read does). In terms of your fragmentation issue - if you have "bands" of buffers, it needn't have too much effect. You can waste *some* space without wasting vast amounts.

Answer (score 3):

This is C# not C++ - you are truly working against the garbage collector here. Memory allocation is generally very fast in C#, also it doesn't suffer from memory fragmentation one of the other main reasons to pre-allocate in C++.

Having said that and you still want to do it I would just use the array index and length, so you can use `Array.Copy` to write at that position.

**Edit:**

As others have pointed out the `ArraySegment<T>` fits your needs better: it limits the consumer to just his slice of the array and it doesn't require to allocate a separate array before updating the content in the original array (as represented by the ArraySegment).

Comment: Agree on the sentiment (this shouldn't be done), disagree on the use of Array.Copy.  That allocates new memory, it doesn't return a subset of the array.  From MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1.aspx

Comment: @Chris: Agreed - Array.Copy would require the class that's using it to allocate their own buffer before copying it to the target buffer, also they would have access to the full array - so yes an `ArraySegment` would be preferable.

Comment: @jon, @Chris, @BrokenGlass: Thanks for the info on ArraySegment<T>, first time I heard about this class. Although, it does not appear to be very useful. Turns out, you cant index an ArraySegment with [], nor you can iterate over it. Apparently, you have to access ArraySegment.Array field, and then index it with [], with the index ids being the original array indices!. Here is a good [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/wim/archive/2006/06/14/ArraySegment-Structure---what-were-they-thinking_3F00_.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Quite old post this is but I have an easy solution. I see that this question has lot's of answers like "you shouldn't". If there is a method to do something, why not use it?

But that aside, you can use the following

```
int[] array = new int[1337];
position = 69;
void* pointer = (void*)Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(array, position);
```

Answer (score 2):

Without going into unmanaged code, you can't return a pointer to the middle of the array in C#, all you can do is return the array index where you want to enter the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you *must* do this, your options include returning an ArraySegment (as Jon Skeet pointed out), or using Streams.  You can return a MemoryStream that is a subset of an array using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezk6t72e.aspx) constructor.  You will need to handle all of your memory reads and writes as stream operations however, not as offset operations.